# XSD javaType adapter result in other languages

Tags: java, c#, jaxb, xsd, adapter

I've an XSD file containing this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://example.org/">

<xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

and when I generate java code with xjc, it produces this:

```
public class Certificate {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(X509CertificateAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")
    protected X509Certificate certificate;

    ....
}
```

and the adapter works fine.

My question is what will happen when I will give my xsd to a no-java client? What will the Certificate C# class (for example) look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave a XSD file as clean as possible by the technology used.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://example.org/">

<xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Java-side, to generate the extra information you should use bindings file (XJB).
Following an example of adding an annotation.

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../yourSchema.xsd">

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='User']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                    name="User">
                </annox:annotate>
            </annox:annotate>
        </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

In this case you need to change this xsd to make it compatible with some other system, becouse you are using specific namespace for java tecnologies. 
(i.e. http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your advise. Could you look on my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903790/xmladapter-for-base64binary-results-in-string)