# XmlAdapter for base64Binary results in String

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, adapter, xjc

I've an XSD file containing this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://example.org/">

<xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

and when I generate java code with xjc, it produces this:

```
public class Certificate {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(X509CertificateAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")
    protected X509Certificate certificate;

    ....
}
```

and the adapter works fine.

My question is why `@XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)` ? Why `type = String.class` and not `byte[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the following:

```java
@XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(X509CertificateAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")
protected X509Certificate certificate;
```

There are a few things to note:

1. The `type` setting on `@XmlElement` is redundant since the `X509CertificateAdapter` already specifies that for the purposes of marshalling & unmarshalling it is going to convert `X508Certificate` to/from a `String`.
2. The `X509CertificateAdapter` converts to/from a `String` instead of a `byte[]` most likely for the purposes of performance, as a conversion to a `byte[]` would cause JAXB to do an additional conversion to `String` to render it correctly in the XML.
3. The `@XmlSchemaType` annotation is used to ensure that when an XML Schema is generated that the node type shows up as `base64Binary` and not `string`.

Answer (score 2):

This class "adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" declares two methods:

```
public X509Certificate unmarshal(String certificateBase64String) throws Exception;
public String marshal(X509Certificate certificate) throws Exception;
```

The first declaration needs of a String to unmarshal some X509Certificate. In this way you can use directly a X509Certificate.

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question

Comment: It's true, I had to adapt my adapter and replace `unmarshal(byte[] certificateBase64)` by `unmarshal(String certificateBase64String)`, and now it works fine, but I would like to understand why do I've to use String, and not `byte[]`, since I declared `<xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">`?

Comment: This is a convention of XJC, this ensures the management of any type used already in generation phase .

In this way he can handle any type xsd as string. 

To my knowledge there is no type of configuration to be able to change this behavior.